# Which modelling method - normal dependent but mixed independents

Tags: distributions, model-selection

My data has normally distributed dependent variables; however the independent variables are an eclectic mix.
They include categorical, nominal, continuous normal, continuous non-normal, and almost bimodal.

Which methods would be most appropriate for this? I can use both linear and nonlinear methods, including neural net. However, I do not have much experience with selecting the appropriate hidden layer activation functions.

I have read that some modelling methods are more appropriate when when dealing with these types of variables.

Answer (score 4):

The fact that the independent variables are an "eclectic mix" does not, by itself, rule out any method, certainly not "regular" OLS regression. OLS regression makes assumptions about the error from the model, as measured by the residuals. It does not make assumptions about the distribution of the independent variables.

That said, other methods may, of course work better for your data. But that depends on the goals of your analysis and the exact nature of your data. e,g, Regression trees are very good at finding particular interactions and can find interactions that occur in only part of the data. Methods based on trees can be even more powerful, but at the expense of some interpretability.

Comment: This is primarily data exploration. In that i want to assume no trends in the data are known. With this is mind there are relationships i expect to see (essentially as a validation for myself) but the main interest is to extract relationships other than these and at the same time a more descriptive result than 'As x increases so does y' which is what we have currently

Comment: Depending on the amount of data, number of variables, shape of relationships and so on, a lot of methods could be used. I strongly recommend a lot of graphical exploration first.

Comment: is there anything reccomeded? Up to this point i have been looking predominantly at model results and interactive distribution plots. Neural nets seem to provide good data fits but only after initial modelling with partition, otherwise they pick out obscure variables before refinement.

Comment: I would say that regression and some variants of it are the easiest to understand. Splines and interactions can be explored. I find neural nets too much of a "black box" when data exploration is the main goal (but I admit I don't know much about neural nets).

Comment: Yes, it is the black box of neural nets which limits thier appeal for finding the internal relationships for this case. I find them very good at generating an accurate model (particularly in respect to consistency between training and validation).I often see Tree methods are rarely mentioned in continuous responses and this was one of my concerns. I do not have an extensive statistical education which i feel is limiting me, something i am keen to address!